# What causes the different behaviors between "var" and "let" when assign them a returned value of a function which throws an error

Tags: javascript, var, throw, let

Please find the code in the image below.
1. Assign the returned value of a function, which throws an error actually, to the variable 'withLet' that declared by using keyword 'let'.
2. call 'withLet', an error occured: 'withLet is not defined'.
3. try to assert 'withLet' using 'let', an error shows that 'withLet' has already been declared.

But the paradox is not exist for 'var' (Please find in the following image).

I'm curious about what caused the different behaviors between these two situations. It's quite wired that 'not defined' an 'already been declared' describe a same variable.

```
let withLet = (function() {throw 'error!'})()
var withVar = (function() {throw 'error!'})()
//VM2470:1 Uncaught error!
//(anonymous) @ VM2470:1
//(anonymous) @ VM2470:1
withLet
//VM2484:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: withLet is not defined at 
//<anonymous>:1:1
//(anonymous) @ VM2484:1
withVar
//undefined
let withLet = 'sth'
//VM2520:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'withLet' has already been 
//declared
//at <anonymous>:1:1
//(anonymous) @ VM2520:1
withVar = 'sth'
//"sth"
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Firefox just prints `undefined`.

Comment: Chrome throws `errors!` for each function call

Comment: i think this is a bug in the engine. `withLet` should be initialized and `undefined` but due to the nature of the variable scope it probably handles it differently.

Comment: important clarification here - this happens in Chrome/V8 but not in Firefox. So, this is implementation specific behaviour.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Declarations of `var` variables get hoisted - the variable name initialization gets hoisted to the top of the containing function (or, if no function, to the top of the outer block). So

```
var withVar = (function() {throw 'error!'})()
```

is parsed by the interpreter as

```
var withVar;
withVar = (function() {throw 'error!'})()
```

The same is not true for `let` - `let` variables become initialized once the `let __` line runs. When there's assignment, the right-hand side is parsed first; if the right-hand side throws an error, it never gets to the left-hand side, and the variable declared with `let` never gets properly initialized; it'll stay in the [demilitarized zone / temporal dead zone](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_variables.html#sec_temporal-dead-zone) forever, so trying to reassign it throws an error.

It's kind of weird because the code is being run in the *console* - ordinarily, JS runs inside a `<script>` tag, and if such an error occurs, *usually* no more code will run, and the fact that a variable declared with `let` is no longer reassignable is the least of your worries.

---

The above was an issue in earlier Chrome versions. But [in Chrome 80+](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/12/devtools), re-declarations of `let` are now permitted, so [the error](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/images/2019/12/letbefore.png)

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'withLet' has already been declared

should no longer occur, regardless of whether the previous initialization of the variable succeeded or not:

[image]

Comment: Just to expand a bit - a variable has three stages to becoming "real". Declaration (that identifier exists), initialization (that idientifier is active and can be used), assignment (there is a value assigned to that identifier). For `var` the declaration + initialisation is hoisted. For `let`/`const` only the *declaration* gets hoisted, the *initialization* comes later - as stated, when the `let myVar` line is reached.