# Error with variable that wasn`t initialized properly with let

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I`m confused about Set type in JS. If you create variable with not properly initialized Set, you cannot use it anymore (as Set nor primitive).
Try in console:

```
let someSet = new Set(4);
/* Uncaught TypeError: number 4 is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at new Set (<anonymous>)*/

someSet
// Uncaught ReferenceError: someSet is not defined 

let someSet = new Set([4])
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'someSet' has already been declared
someSet
// Uncaught ReferenceError: someSet is not defined

let someSet = 'ho-ho-ho'
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'someSet' has already been declared

someSet = 'ho-ho-ho'
// Uncaught ReferenceError: someSet is not defined
```

Can you explain me why?
 See screen:

[image]

Comment: please add code here, not images.

Comment: Just type what is in the screenshot yourself, because your script with this code will fail after 1st line

Comment: I can't see imgur images because of the restrictions in my workplace.

Comment: Added some code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between declared and defined variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54979906/is-there-any-difference-between-declared-and-defined-variable) and [What causes the different behaviors between “var” and “let” when assign them a returned value of a function which throws an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54231651)

Comment: @adiga - Good find!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is pretty much something that can only happen on the console, since in real code if the `new Set` part of `let someSet = new Set(4);` failed, the error would take you out of the scope where `let someSet` was and so this question wouldn't come up.

Interactive consoles like the ones in browsers have to play some games with scope and such. You've ended up with a variable that's *declared* but not *initialized* (made ready for use); it's forever in the Temporal Dead Zone (TDZ), because the spec's [InitializeBinding](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-declarative-environment-records-initializebinding-n-v) operation has never been performed on it. (Variables are "bindings" in an environment object [there are other kinds of bindings as well].) Unlike the variable bindings created by `var`, the ones created by `let` can be *uninitialized*. Here's an example:

```
{
    // `x` is *declared* upon entry to this scope, but not *initialized* yet
    x = 5; // Fails because the `x` binding isn't initialized yet
    let x;
}
```

Again, your exact example is only possible in a console like Chrome's console. If `new Set(4)` didn't throw an error, the line `let someSet = new Set(4);` would do these things, in this order:

1. Declare (but not initialize) the variable (binding) `someSet`
2. Evaluate the initializer `new Set(4)`
3. Use the resulting value from #2 to initialize the variable

The problem is that since `new Set(4)` threw an error, step 3 never occurred. In a normal environment, that error would take you out of the scope where `someSet` was declared, but not in Chrome's console. As a result, you can't use `someSet` at all, because you can't declare it again (it's already been declared), and you can't read its value (it doesn't have one, it's uninitialized), and you can't write a value to it (because the operation that does that, [SetMutableBinding](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-declarative-environment-records-setmutablebinding-n-v-s), checks whether the variable has been initialized and fails if it hasn't — because that's how the TDZ works).

Comment: [Link to the temporal dead zone documentation of let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone)

Comment: yeap. works with `var` at first place. so that means, that the problem is with `let`, but not `Set` type

Comment: @MusicalEcho - Yes, this has nothing to do with `Set`. It's not a problem with `let`; you could argue it's a problem with Chrome's console.

Comment: @MusicalEcho - No worries. I couldn't help myself and updated it further. :-)